# Missing extension logos on OS X

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I think the title says it all.
I don't seem to have the logos for the extensions in the side bar.
Is this intentional or an issue? Did not find any related issues on Github.

Comment: Sorry, my bad: "side bar"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side bar was actually a little bit smaller than it should have been.

Comment: It is an epic fail that I had to search for this again! : /

Answer (score -1):

Have you set a file icon theme?

Code -> Preferences -> File Icon Theme.

https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/09/08/icon-themes

Comment: I'm talking about the icon next to the extensions. (Ctrl+Shift+x)